# Не работает else If в JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, if

Когда ввожу 1 и 4 все нормально 1 < 4, но когда 4 и 1 то показывает 4 = 4 пробовал все и ничего не получилось. Помогите!!! Спасибо

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    var a = prompt("Num:");
    var b = prompt("Num 2:");
        for (;;) {
                if (a > b) {
                    document.write(a, ' > ' ,b);
                }
                else if (a = b) {
                    document.write(a, ' = ' ,b);
                }
                else if (a < b) {
                    document.write(a, ' < ' ,b);
                }
                else {
                    document.write('Error');
                };
                break;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Зачем здесь цикл for? Он не делает абсолютно ничего.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас во втором условии идёт присваивание `=` а надо сравнение `==`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    var a = prompt("Num:");
    var b = prompt("Num 2:");
        for (;;) {
                if (a > b) {
                    document.write(a, ' > ' ,b);
                }
                else if (a == b) {
                    document.write(a, ' = ' ,b);
                }
                else if (a < b) {
                    document.write(a, ' < ' ,b);
                }
                else {
                    document.write('Error');
                };
                break;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Поправочка, сравнивать все же стоит `===` xDDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev поправочку на поправочку. Надо все же привести к числу переменные.))